# pause an activity meanwhile another one is running

Tags: android, multithreading, sleep, voice

I would like to get voice recognition using just one method.

In order to do that i've created 3 classes

the main class

```
public class Index extends Activity {

    private Button boton;
    private EditText texto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index);
        boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton);
        texto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.texto);
        boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                texto.setText(IVRecognition.getInstancia().getComando(Index.this));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the intermediate

```
public class IVRecognition {

    //*******************singleton********************

    private static IVRecognition instancia;

    private IVRecognition (){}

    public static IVRecognition getInstancia(){
        if (instancia==null) instancia = new IVRecognition();
        return instancia;
    }

    //************************************************

    public static String resultado = null;

    public String getComando(Context content){
        Intent intent = new Intent(content, VRecognition.class);
        content.startActivity(intent);

        //pause here untill VRecognition.onActivityResult is executed

        return resultado;
    }
}
```

and the recognition one

```
public class VRecognition extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startRecognition();
    }

    public void startRecognition (){
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE,this.getPackageName());
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1 /*VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE*/);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == 1 /*VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE*/ && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            IVRecognition.getInstancia().resultado = result.get(0);
        }
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I call `VRecognition` activity using `content.startActivity(intent);`  the execution of the aplication keeps on going, so the variable called `resultado` has null value until `onActivityResult` is executed, which results in a null return value.

Hope you can help me. Cheers

Comment: *Never* sleep the UI thread. Why are you not calling the startActivityFoResult in your main activity?

Comment: Hi seiterm, thank you for your advice, I have to integrate it into another aplication, so it will be called many times. I tried changing   content.startActivity(intent); for ((Activity)content).startActivityForResult(intent,1); but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ian's answer is good. But from your comment, I'd recommend using an IntentService and the BroadcastManager. That way you don't need the intermediate activity. You call the `startService(intent)` from any activity that wants the VR result (and implements BroadcastReceiver). Then the IntentService calls `startActivityForResult(intent,1)` and Broadcasts the result.

More info:
http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html

Comment: Hi seiterm, thanks for your time and concern, I'm rookie programming on android devices, I'm going to investigate abuot IntentService  and BroadcastManager, and I will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to pause execution until voice recognition is complete. You may want to rethink this; you're calling `getComando()` from your UI thread, so your application UI will be frozen until recognition is complete. In the (probably quite likely) event that recognition takes more than five seconds, the system will pop up an Application Not Responding dialog. (Also, since you're implementing `getComando()` by starting another activity within your process, blocking the UI thread in `getComando()` would prevent recognition from ever running.)

The right way to do this is to use a completion callback. For instance, you could create an IVRecognitionListener interface:

`public interface IVRecognitionListener {
  public void onRecognitionComplete(String resultado);
}`

and pass an instance of that to `getComando()`. Then instead of just setting `IVRecognition.resultado` in `onActivityResult()`, you could call `onRecognitionComplete()` to notify the caller of the result.

Comment: Hi Ian , thanks for your advice, I definitely will not stop the execution, I am interested in your proposed solution, I will study it and keep you posted

Comment: seiterm's answer is more correct--you shouldn't be starting an activity with no UI, that's what services are for. The other advantage to using a service+broadcast is that you won't be holding a reference to the caller as you would be with my proposed solution. If the caller is an activity, it would be fantastically easy to end up with a dangling reference.